# rsync for backups: without --remove option and rotations…?

Tags: rsync

Is reasonably safe to use rsync (without --delete option) to make my daily backups and keep only 1 copy on the backup server (instead of having multiple copies with rotations) ?

If I don't enable the --delete option, any backup file won't be ever deleted, correct ?

Comment: Whether it's safe or not depends on what you are trying to backup. If it's anything critical you should probably have two backups or at least have your backup server RAID'ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files won't be deleted, but they'll be overwritten with modified versions. I wouldn't regard this as safe myself -- if you mess up a file and don't notice for a day, then you've lost the good version.